# d3.js - only add circle element not update existing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, append, data-visualization

I'm just getting into [d3.js](http://d3js.org) and I currently have a circle in the background of my svg. I now want to add 5 additional circles bound to special data.

If I do that with selectAll unfortunately only 4 circles with the new data are appended. the first of the 5 seems to select the existing one and is not updated.

How can I have an existing circle in my svg and add 5 other circles bound to new data and end up with 6 circles in total?

Here's some of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//draw svg
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 600);
//add group to contain all circles
var svgGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

//add bg circle
var bgCircle = svgGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 300).attr("cy", 300).attr("r", 120)
    .attr("fill", "black");

//add circles
var circles = svgGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .data([
        {cx: "250", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "300", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "350", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "400", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "450", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
    ])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; }) });
```

you should see 4 red circles and a black one in the background.
I now want 5 red circles and have the black still in the background.

Please, somebody tell me how to do that.
I tried to achieve it by understanding enter, update and exit of d3, but that did not help too much...

Thanks in advance
cheers

Comment: just as a comment: I'm also using the jQuery library to check if the document is ready (first line). so to reproduce my code, one would have to write an html with an existing body tag and include jQuery and my file above...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way how to do it.
By selecting not the circle elements but rather select a class name I can have exclude the old circle from the new selection and therefore 5 elements are still without bound data and d3 adds 5 elements.

see sample code here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//draw svg
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 600);
//add group to contain all circles
var svgGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

//add bg circle
var bgCircle = svgGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 300).attr("cy", 300).attr("r", 120)
    .attr("fill", "black");

//add circles
var circles = svgGroup.selectAll(".dataCircle")
    .data([
        {cx: "250", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "300", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "350", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "400", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
        {cx: "450", cy: "300", r: "12", color: "red"},
    ])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })



});
```

Look at the .circleData class i'm selecting.
The resulting HTML does not have the class anywhere... it's probably a virtual selection which is not important anymore.
Maybe someone could explain some details about the behaviour and whether this is a good method to do that or a rather bad one.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are storing circle attributes as data ?

Comment: @Ian no, I guess that was code I took from an example originally. And maybe I did not understand this 'data' back then and thought it was necessary... So no reason for that